# Does one need initiation from a guru to recite vedas?

Tags: scripture, vedas, vedanta, stotra, yajur-veda

I’m thinking of reciting medha suktam and shraddha suktam daily. I have read that these suktams are a part of the vedas. Does one need initiation from a guru for reciting vedas or one can recite them like a stotra?

Comment: Yes, any part of the Vedas needs vedic initiation and a guru.

Comment: Initiation from a guru is a pre-requisite for such things

Comment: Thus Vedas must be **strictly** learned  only after initiation and under the guidance of a  Guru.Chanting Mantras or Suktams with improper pronunciations  would most probably be counterproductive.Also Recitation without interpretation and getting the essence of the scripture is as good as not reading it in the first place.That is why Prior Sanskrit knowledge and interpretation under Guru's watchful eye is highly encouraged; Chances are with our mind full of ego and body-identification  we might miss the hidden meaning behind the verses and come up with our own twisted meanings.

Comment: Ok. Understood. And Do Stotrams also need initiation ?

Comment: Yes they do require initiation.Guru according to your spiritual lvl guides you throughout your journey and directs you to read specific texts/mantras/stotrams/suktams.

Comment: @Rāmachandra Sir but I've a doubt. I don't think that every stotra requires it. Some stotras are general too and can be recited by anybody like Hanuman Chalisa, Shiva Tandava Stotra etc. Moreover, somebody also said me that sometimes Stotras themselves say that whether they're for dwijas or not but I've not come across such a stotra yet.

Comment: @LSSJ Broly Sir Initiation is a must for All Mantras and Suktams under the Vedas .Stotrams on the other hand i would say it depends, some require some don't but all of them need to be recited only under the guidance of a Guru.Some common ones like you mentioned do not but it was only after initiation that i was allowed to recite Ram Raksha Stotram,Maruti Stotram and Vishnu Sahasranama Stotram.

Comment: Yes I was also talking about Stotras and General Prayers...For Mantras suktams Tantras etc. they are must :)

Comment: You do not need initiation from a guru, but you do need to learn the proper pronunciation from a competent teacher. Vedas are mantras - literally sounds, vibrations. If you do not pronounce the sound correctly, make the correct sound vibration, it can have no effect, or sometimes, the opposite effect desired.